# Verifying WebKit Versions for iOS 16 and iOS 17 Builds and Assessing Commit Impact

Tags: ios, webkit, xcode15, ios17

I have noticed that some behaviors in WKWebView are different when building with Xcode 15 for iOS 17 compared to iOS 16. I suspect that this difference may be attributed to the commit at [Remove iOS-only NSUserDefaults-backed UA override](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/commit/6a68b0c65d6c2504c8455ce9f88b870fb4d6ed94).

However, since this is just my speculation, I would like to confirm the reason. To do so, I want to check the WebKit version when building for iOS 16 and 17 and verify if the changes made in that commit are included in the respective release versions of [WebKit](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit).

I attempted debugging using `navigator.userAgent`, but the values for iOS 16 and 17 appear to be the same, making it challenging to determine what has changed.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148
```

How can I verify the WebKit version used for iOS 16 and iOS 17 builds and determine if the content of a specific commit has influenced that version?